# MarkLogic Geospatial representation and subsequent search

Tags: search, geospatial, marklogic, representation

I have a flat file containing a property/value: `"Geolocation": "(32.15672444830, -110.877085494)"`. In order to accommodate MarkLogic Geospatical search, I believe "Geolocation" needs to be transformed and conform certain format. May I know what that format looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My result indicates that `"Geolocation": "(32.15672444830, -110.877085494)"` is invalid representation. If the property is transformed and conformed through API, then Geospatial query returns the expected result:

```
{
"State": "IL", 
"City": "Chicago", 
"indexCancer": "5", 
"Geolocation": [
41.84, 
-87.69
]
}

{
"State": "PA", 
"City": "Allentown", 
"indexCancer": "6", 
"Geolocation": "40.61, -75.48"
}

{
"State": "MA", 
"City": "Boston", 
"indexCancer": "4.8", 
"Geolocation": [
42.32, 
-71.10
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have geospatial point indexes, and geospatial region indexes. The point indexes either take the stringified version of cts.point, or you can indicate latitude and longitude separately. You can use cts.point directly inside JSON to get the string representation:

```
let res = {
  location: cts.point(1,2)
};

res;
```

Region index only allows stringified versions of cts.point, cts.linestring, cts.circle, cts.box, and cts.polygon. Those can be embedded directly inside JSON as well. See also the geospatial constructors help page:

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts/geospatial-constructors

HTH!

Comment: Thanks!  `https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/geospatial#id_72797` .  In order to perform path/property Point/Child Point/Pair Point query, document shall conform to certain structure: ` {"coords": "1.0 2.0" } {"coords": [1.0, 2.0] }`. The query needed is something like: I feed in a lat/lon, MarkLogic can return an exact city value. One city name matches exact one lat/lon pair (the origin "Geolocation") in one document.

Comment: `cts.point(32.15672444830, -110.877085494) ` returns: `32.156724,-110.87709`.  Do you mean to say the value  of`"Geolocation": "(32.15672444830, -110.877085494)"` needs be transformed as `32.156724,-110.87709` or the document layout AND the value must be transformed?

Comment: You can name your properties or elements whatever you like, as long as your index settings match with it. Enable the 'reject' flag to make sure ML understands and tolerates what you feed it. It might ignore the parentheses, but not sure.